# How do I fix this simple Aurelia css issue?

Tags: html, css

I have basically downloaded and installed all necessary dependencies and plugins for Aurelia, and I am running their generic "todo" project, which is just a "hello world" application, but for the life of me I cant figure out why my styles.css wont change any of the stylings on my html elements. Could anyone provide a little insight for me, I am just beginning my journey in web development and would really appreciate the assistance.
Styles.css

```
    h1{
      background-color: red;
    }
```

app.html

```
    <template>
      <h1>${message}</h1>
      <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<template>
 <require from="styles.css"></require>
 <h1>${message}</h1>
</template>
```

Or alternatively in your `webpack.config.js` add it like this:

```
plugins: [
  ...
  new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'src/css/styles.css', to: 'styles.css' }
  ])
]
```

And then you can link to it in your `index.ejs`, so include this in your `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  ...
</head>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the assistance.